# Is there any way to pass a symbol like # to android CallIntents?

Tags: java, android

Currently I am trying to create an android app which handles out going phone calls to our call manager.
The problem is the `URI.parse()` method which deletes all symbols that are not allowed in a phone number, but it had to pass an number which has a "#" in in it.

Is there any way to pass the whole number like "012347#5687" to the android action_call intent?

Comment: I  saw a tricky way how to auto press keys after call, it was a # there too

Comment: Do you know where you saw this solution?
It would be very useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code and works like a charm

```
    Intent my_callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    my_callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*131%23"));
```

where %23 represents #

hope this help

Comment: The question that still holds is how the target app is going to handle "%23".. I mean does it handles it implicitly?

Comment: yes, I think so, I tried it with some different dialers and on different devices